# Dynamic Colours For Pie Chart

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

Take the colours from a JSON result set and apply to an ng2-charts pie chart

Each result I return from the database has a value and a colour.

E.g. 
TicketType / No of Tickets / Report Colour

Concert       /     4      /       #C44F44

Gamer Night    /    10       /     #F88912

There are be varying numbers of results and each have different colours - I need to have the 'pieChartColors' value from ng2-charts to use these dynamic values.

I have tried to replace the example value:

```
**pieChartColors: any[] = [{  backgroundColor: ['#3B55E6', '#EB4E36', '#43D29E', '#32CBD8', '#E8C63B', '#28C63B', '#38C63B', '#48C63B', '#58C63B', '#68C63B', '#78C63B'] }];**
```

with

```
pieChartColors: any[] = [{ backgroundColor: this.arrColours }];
```

I have tried other ways but each time I try either there are no colours or a get all grey.

component.ts

```
    this.arr = [];
    this.arrLabels = [];
    this.arrColours = [];

    for (let stat of this.ticketType) {
        this.arr.push(stat.noOfTickets);
        this.arrLabels.push(stat.ticketType);
        this.arrColours.push(stat.reportColour);

    }
```

component.html

```
   <canvas *ngIf='resultSet' baseChart height="70" 
    [data]="arr"
    [labels]="arrLabels" 
    [options]="PieChartOptions" 
    [colors]="pieChartColors"
    [chartType]="pieChartType">
    </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply push new values into the labels, data and colors array:

```js
addSlice() {
  this.pieChartLabels.push('Concert');
  this.pieChartData.push(4);
  this.pieChartColors[0].backgroundColor.push('#C44F44');
}
```

[image]

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-pie-template-eiz7tx)